# How tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory display output to console

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, output

I am using the below function to read images from a directory

```
   train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(directory=image_dataset_path,
                                                                   validation_split=0.2,
                                                                    subset='training',
                                                                    batch_size=32,
                                                                    color_mode='rgb',
                                                                    seed=1)
```

and it display below text in the output

```
Found 284 files belonging to 5 classes.
Using 228 files for training.
```

After exploring the above function [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/keras/preprocessing/image_dataset.py) I am not able to find out how it is displaying the text in the console. One thing that I noticed is that the output of the function is a dataset but how does it generate the text in console?

Please help me understand How tf.keras is showing this output in the console. What is the exact code behind this?

Comment: what do you mean by text in the output?

Comment: It Generates a `tf.data.Dataset` from image files in a directory and the other is the output text in the console which I showed above. So I am referring to that by saying the text in the output. Changed my wording, hope this is more clear now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those two statements are the result of two helper functions used by `tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory`.

See the relevant part of those functions below:

- [dataset_utils.index_directory](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/401dc1b3db4e7412f4fc50f96c25fd564d593f4c/tensorflow/python/keras/preprocessing/dataset_utils.py#L28).

  ```
  if labels is None:
   print('Found %d files.' % (len(filenames),))
   else:
     print('Found %d files belonging to %d classes.' %
         (len(filenames), len(class_names)))
  ```
- [dataset_utils.get_training_or_validation_split](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/401dc1b3db4e7412f4fc50f96c25fd564d593f4c/tensorflow/python/keras/preprocessing/dataset_utils.py#L166)

  ```
  if subset == 'training':
      print('Using %d files for training.' % (len(samples) - num_val_samples,))
      samples = samples[:-num_val_samples]
      labels = labels[:-num_val_samples]
  ```

Those two helper functions simply print those messages in the standard output as a way to provide information to the developer.